# Mongo: mongodump and the config database error

Tags: mongodb, mongodump

I've setup a backup script on my Ubuntu box using mongodump. However this currently doesn't work because of an error when attempting to dump the built in config database:

[image]

(Apologies for the image, I couldn't copy paste from the terminal I used)

How can I fix this? I either need to add the right permissions to my user, or exclude the config database. Ideally I'd like mongodump to ignore errors on any particular database so I still get a useful backup.

Here is the user I'm using to login as, as defined in the admin database:

```
{
    "_id" : "admin.admin",
    "userId" : UUID("b1928c55-fbaa-4196-9e7c-93e9139501ed"),
    "user" : "admin",
    "db" : "admin",
    "roles" : [ 
        {
            "role" : "userAdminAnyDatabase",
            "db" : "admin"
        }, 
        {
            "role" : "dbAdminAnyDatabase",
            "db" : "admin"
        }, 
        {
            "role" : "readWriteAnyDatabase",
            "db" : "admin"
        }
    ],
    "mechanisms" : [ 
        "SCRAM-SHA-1", 
        "SCRAM-SHA-256"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have the required privileges for the **config** database.

See https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/built-in-roles/ :

> **readWriteAnyDatabase**
>
> Provides the same privileges as readWrite on **all databases except** local and **config**.
>
> **userAdminAnyDatabase**
>
> Provides the same access to user administration operations as userAdmin on **all databases except** local and **config**.
>
> **dbAdminAnyDatabase**
>
> Provides the same privileges as dbAdmin on **all databases except** local and **config**.

For mongodump, use the `backup` role.

> The admin database includes the
>   following roles for backing up and restoring data:
>
> **backup**
>
> Provides minimal privileges needed for backing up data. This role provides sufficient privileges to use the MongoDB Cloud Manager backup
>   agent, Ops Manager backup agent, or to use **mongodump** to back up an
>   entire mongod instance.

Specifics about mongodump https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongodump/ :

> Required Access
>
> To run mongodump against a MongoDB deployment that has access control
>   enabled, you must have privileges that grant find action for each
>   database to back up. The built-in **backup** role provides the required
>   privileges to perform backup of any and all databases.